# How to make the bibentry text appear below the citekey with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I want to set the text of a citeentry below the citekey with a space to the left border. My current solution sets the text to the next line but the space between key and text is still the same. This is my current code for the bibliography settings:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=10, style=alphabetic, natbib=true, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}\thefield{label}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}


\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibparens}[1]{{\ifcitation{\bibleftbracket#1\bibrightbracket}
{\bibleftparen#1\bibrightparen}}}
\renewcommand*{\bibopenparen}[1]{{\ifcitation{\bibleftbracket#1}        {\bibleftparen#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\bibcloseparen}{{\ifcitation{\bibrightbracket}{\bibrightparen}}}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
\\    
}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,bibtotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{helvet}

\input{bibliographysettings}

\bibliography{literatur}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
 An example text. \parencite[]{Test}

\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=subbibliography, 
 title={Literaturverzeichnis}] 

\end{document}
```

Bib-File:

```
 @Book{Test,
    Title                    = {Example},
    Author                   = {Example, E.}, 
    Publisher                = {Example Example Example},
    Year                     = {1970},
    Label                    = {\ 1970}
  }
```

[image]

Edit:
I've added the line from Lopezo. It just helps, when the bibentrytext is only one line. If its longer i have a new problem:

[image]

The whole text should have the same space to the left border. Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks for you advises. i added a minimal example and the bib file code. sorry for the circumstances --> first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it from your code is to add this third line in:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list{
      \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelalpha}}%
      \addspace \\
    }
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{2em}}
}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \\
}
```

**Edit** This is an update of the first solution

Comment: thank you for the answer. but it helps just a little bit (see edit).

Comment: I update my answer, does it works for you?